# How do I fix this AttributeError in my interactions.py code?

Tags: python, discord-interactions

In my interactions.py code, I have two different bot commands. One to get information about a user's products and one to retrieve a certain product. Whenever I run my code, I get `AttributeError: 'Command' object has no attribute '_options'`.
This is my code:

```
import interactions, requests

bot = interactions.Client(token="tokenhere")


@bot.command(
    name="products",
    description="Get a list of all your products",
    scope=scopeid,
)
@interactions.option('Your roblox UserID',name='UserID', type=interactions.OptionType.INTEGER , required=True)
@bot.command(
    name="retrieve",
    description="Retrieve a certain product that you own",
    scope=scopeid,
    options=[
        interactions.Option(
            name='product',
            description='the product you would like to retrieve',
            type=interactions.OptionType.STRING,
            required=True
        )
    ]
)
async def products(ctx: interactions.CommandContext, userid: int):
    a = str(requests.get('https://jedistuff22.pythonanywhere.com/products/' + str(userid)).text)
    await ctx.send(a)
async def retrieve(ctx: interactions.CommandContext, product: str):
    a = ctx.author.user.username + '#' + ctx.author.user.discriminator
    print(a)
    await ctx.send(a)

bot.start()
```

For some reason, my code works when i just have one command but just flat out stops working when I have two.

I'm really stumped with this error. I have been looking online for about the past day and I am yet to find something that could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've used the same bot.command() decorator to define two bot commands. Because the bot.command() method can only define one command at a time, you must define each command separately.

```
import interactions
import requests

bot = interactions.Client(token="tokenhere")

@bot.command(
    name="products",
    description="Get a list of all your products",
    scope=scopeid,
)
@interactions.option('Your roblox UserID',name='UserID', type=interactions.OptionType.INTEGER , required=True)
async def products(ctx: interactions.CommandContext, userid: int):
    a = str(requests.get('https://jedistuff22.pythonanywhere.com/products/' + str(userid)).text)
    await ctx.send(a)

@bot.command(
    name="retrieve",
    description="Retrieve a certain product that you own",
    scope=scopeid,
)
@interactions.option(
    name='product',
    description='the product you would like to retrieve',
    type=interactions.OptionType.STRING,
    required=True
)
async def retrieve(ctx: interactions.CommandContext, product: str):
    a = ctx.author.user.username + '#' + ctx.author.user.discriminator
    print(a)
    await ctx.send(a)

bot.start()
```